# Review First Post shows question even when filter is set to answers

Tags: support, bug, first-post-review

I have set *answers* as filter in First Post Review Queue but it presented me a question.

Also the question shows as asked today in the review screen even though it was asked 22 days ago as seen in the question itself.

Is this a bug or audit?

Screenshot from review queue

[image: review screenshot]

Screenshot of the question
[image: question acreenshot]

Comment: That looks like an audit :) I expect the audit system doesn't look at the filters.

Comment: @Scratte seem to be audit and I skipped it